# search mailchimp list by something else than email

Tags: php, email, mailchimp

currently all i can find is that the api only allow searching by email which is many cases not helpful because if the user wants to change his subscribing email he either have to

- do something like this > http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/how-subscribers-can-update-their-profiles
- or i will have the new & old email from the user on the list because `memberInfo()` will return false because its a new given email.
- also `$update_existing=true` is only used incase the user wants to change his (fname,lname) which in most cases they only want to change the email it self not the other info.

so does anyone knows a better way on how to handle subscribing/unsubscribing users using something else other than the email ???

**Dublication :**
[check if user is in a list with mailchimp API V2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22527541/check-if-user-is-in-a-list-with-mailchimp-api-v2-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can search by anything u want through

https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/helper/search-members.php i.e

`MailchimpWrapper::helper()->searchMembers('what to search by', 'list_id');`

,and to update the user info u can use

https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/update-member.php i.e

```
MailchimpWrapper::lists()->updateMember(
    'list_id',
    ['email' => $old_email],
    ['new-email' => $new_email],
    'html',
    false
);
```